# Site.js connection timeout

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to launch site.js script on my page(http://www.erzis.ct8.pl), but it keeps showing me this error.

```
[2017-01-04 16:42:34.936] [TRACE] [default] - Strange error
[2017-01-04 16:42:34.936] [DEBUG] [default] - { [Error: listen EPERM 0.0.0.0:8080]
code: 'EPERM',
errno: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'listen',
address: '0.0.0.0',
port: 8080 }
Error: listen EPERM 0.0.0.0:8080
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1237:19)
at listen (net.js:1286:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
at Server.listen.Server.attach (/usr/home/erzis/domains/erzis.ct8.pl/public_html/Bot/BOT/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:228:9)
at null._onTimeout (/usr/home/erzis/domains/erzis.ct8.pl/public_html/Bot/BOT/site.js:618:29)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Comment: Try the command with `sudo ...`

Comment: I'm using hosting called ct8 and I don't root privilages.